# Fixing the error code: "Can't convert object of type java.lang.String to type"

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-platform, firebase-realtime-database

I'm creating my first Android app which is a forum app wherein users can post.

I read a lot of the same error, but I can't figure it out to solve my problem. I got the error once I call the method LoadPost(); which fetches the data from Direbase straight to my RecycleView.

[Here is my Firebase data structure:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5qejZ.png)

Here's my ViewHolder:

```
public class MyViewHolder3 extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
CircleImageView circleImageView;
TextView user_name, user_power, user_dep, date_posted, user_post_description, upvote_count;
Button upvote_btn, comment_btn;

public MyViewHolder3(@NonNull View itemView) {
    super(itemView);
    circleImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.circleImageView);
    user_name = itemView.findViewById(R.id.user_name);
    user_power = itemView.findViewById(R.id.user_power);
    user_dep = itemView.findViewById(R.id.user_dep);
    date_posted = itemView.findViewById(R.id.date_posted);
    user_post_description = itemView.findViewById(R.id.user_post_description);
    upvote_count = itemView.findViewById(R.id.upvote_count);

    upvote_btn = itemView.findViewById(R.id.upvote_btn);
    comment_btn = itemView.findViewById(R.id.comment_btn);

}
```

Here's my Post class:

```
public class Post {

private String postdescription, userdep, date, username, userpower, userprofileimage;

public Post() {
}

public String getPostdescription() {
    return postdescription;
}

public void setPostdescription(String postdescription) {
    this.postdescription = postdescription;
}

public String getUserdep() {
    return userdep;
}

public void setUserdep(String userdep) {
    this.userdep = userdep;
}

public String getDate() {
    return date;
}

public void setDate(String date) {
    this.date = date;
}

public String getUsername() {
    return username;
}

public void setUsername(String username) {
    this.username = username;
}

public String getUserpower() {
    return userpower;
}

public void setUserpower(String userpower) {
    this.userpower = userpower;
}

public String getUserprofileimage() {
    return userprofileimage;
}

public void setUserprofileimage(String userprofileimage) {
    this.userprofileimage = userprofileimage;
}

public Post(String postdescription, String userdep, String date, String username, String userpower, String userprofileimage) {
    this.postdescription = postdescription;
    this.userdep = userdep;
    this.date = date;
    this.username = username;
    this.userpower = userpower;
    this.userprofileimage = userprofileimage;
}
```

Here's my LoadPost() method:

```
    private void LoadPost() {

    options = new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<Post>().setQuery(ForumRef,Post.class).build();
    adapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Post, MyViewHolder3>(options) {
        @Override
        protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder3 holder, int position, @NonNull Post model) {
        holder.user_post_description.setText(model.getPostdescription());
        holder.user_dep.setText(model.getUserdep());
        holder.date_posted.setText(model.getDate());
        holder.user_name.setText(model.getUsername());
        holder.user_power.setText(model.getUserpower());
        Picasso.get().load(model.getUserprofileimage()).into(holder.circleImageView);
        }

        @NonNull
        @Override
        public MyViewHolder3 onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.all_post_layout2,parent,false);
            return new MyViewHolder3(view);
        }
    };
    adapter.startListening();
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

And here's the error code I got:

```
com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Can't convert object of type java.lang.String to type com.example.chitchat.Post
```

Comment: How is `ForumRef` defined?

Comment: Hi Alex, ForumRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference.child("Forums").child(PostKey); wherein PostKey contained the specific Forum name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you're passing the following reference:

```
ForumRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference.child("Forums").child(PostKey);
```

To:

```
.setQuery(ForumRef,Post.class)
```

It means that the adapter expects to render on the screen `Post` objects. If you take a closer look at your database schema, under the post key (`1st`) node, you can find a `Post` object and two strings, the `count` and the `forumname`:

[image]

See, `IUSH...2Mon`, `count`, and `forumname` are children that exist under the exact same (`1st`) node. So when reading the data from the database, the Firebase-UI library tries to map each child under the above reference into an object of type `Post`, which is actually not possible since the last two children are strings. To solve this, you have to move those two strings to a different location. As soon as inside that node will only exist `Post` objects, then the error will go away.